# How to increase the height of a Jscrollpane after it is visible?

Tags: java, swing, resize

My customer have lib of classes that extends swing components. One class extends Jscrollpane. There is a case when he knows what will be displayed in it. ( A size expandable text component, like a text field)

Until now he had a init method called from the constructor that sets scrollbars never.

Now he would like to change the constructor to take a boolean, true, that will in the init method set horizontal scrollbar as_needed when using true.

He also wants the height of the scrollbar increase in the way preferredsize.height + 16 in advance. (Even when the scrollbar is not showing)

He suggest it to be done in the init method which is executed before it is visible. But when I debug the code preferredsize.height is 0. So I can not calculate the extender height to send into setPreferredSize.

I need to figurer out a way to either know the size of the JScrollPane before but is visible. Or a way to increase the size after it is visible.

Do you guys see any solution for this problem?

I have tried to add a changelistener that detected f the scrollbar was visible and then increase the height. The outcome was not so good UI, since the height switched when scrollbar was or not was visible. Not exact what the customer wanted.

Comment: This question is not a good fit with SO - it is too broad. Maybe try SuperUser?

Comment: This sounds like a problem that is solved with [layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/).  Is this customer using a null layout?

Comment: Hello, the class that extends the JScrollPane got a special/custom layout, that implements layoutConatiner. So it does not use a null layout. How ever if I am not wrong layoutConatiner is executed after the init. I am nut sure when the prefferdsize is supposed to be set. Somethimg tells me that there is somerhing important to think about regarding prefferdsize when using custom layout managers.

Comment: I’m wondering about the layout of the parent container where the JScrollPane resides, more than the layout of the JScrollPane itself.

Comment: Increase the Scroll Bar? Layout Managers take care of this. This (I think) is one of those times where an Image can possibly tell a thousand words. If the contents that will be displayed within the child component of the JScrollPane, then perhaps [FontMetrics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) can be used to determine whether or not sizing even needs to take place.

Answer (score 0):

When you know the content of a component has changed, and the size should be re-evaluated by the layout manager then you call

- validate()
- repaint()

and Swing should take care.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the parent container used jgoodies. I could then easily increase the space for this (the children) component upon the case when the boolean I mentioned was true.